# calling the object name is returning the output but calling actual function name does not gives the output. why?

Tags: python, python-2.7

whenever I call a function with its name it gives address position, but if I assigned it to new object then calling by new object name gives proper output.

```
def is_called():
  def is_returned():
    print("Hello")
  return is_returned

new = is_called()

new()     #Outputs "Hello"
```

but when I call with only function name `is_called()`, I don't get any output.

I'm new to Python/Programming languages.

Comment: Indentation is not clear. Return statement is out of place. Also it would be great if you could format a little using markdown - e.g. second-last line is unclear. What did you call which didn't return anything?

Comment: If you're new to python, where did you get this code from?

Answer (score 1):

Calling `is_called` returns a function object, so to call the function that `is_called` returns you should use another set of parentheses:

```
is_called()()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a function. In Python, functions are "first class objects",  which means they are objects. If you wanted to get "Hello" with your current code, you'd have to call

```
is_called()()
```

because you're returning a function object, not the results of the function.

You could also fix is_called() to return

```
is_returned()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_called():
    def is_returned():
        print("Hello")
    return is_returned

new = is_called()
new() ## Important Line
```

OR

```
def is_called():
    def is_returned():
        print("Hello")
    return is_returned() ## Important Line 

is_called()
#OR
new = is_called ## Important Line
new()
```